# How to implement redirect after sign up in Express?

Tags: express

All:

I am pretty new to Express.js, I wonder how can I redirect to home page(with successful logged in indicator) after user successfully signs up?

For example:

**signup.html**

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

**Handler**

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    // How to handle this to redirect to home page
    // I only have a GET handler for home page
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Express, you can send a redirect using `response.redirect('/');`

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

Comment: thanks, this is what confused me. I only have a GET handler for "/" route, when I redirect, how can it be triggerred?

Comment: Instead of using `router.get('/', () => {})` you might want to consider `router.use('/', () => {})` which applies to post requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.post('/login')` you can simply redirect using `res.redirect()`;

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
 // Authenticate the user

 if (authenticated)
   return res.redirect('/<logged-in-route');

 return res.sendStatus(401);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this is what confused me. I only have a GET handler for "/" route, when I redirect, how can it be triggerred?

Comment: This will make the request using `GET`

Comment: Thanks, so redirect always change the HEADER method to GET? Or How can I decide what Method handler to use?

Comment: Not sure how you can change it but you're simply loading the resource at the set `Location` header. `GET` is the default method for resource loading so it should just use that once its there.